# What is difference between AuthenticationScheme and ClientAuthenticationScheme in Spring oAuth2?

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

We have `setClientAuthenticationScheme()` and `setAuthenticationScheme()` in spring oauth2.

I understand that `ClientAuthenticationScheme` will locate the `clientID` and `secret`. But what does `setAuthenticationScheme()` do - Is it for other requestparameters ?

Answer (score 2):

I think I found it.. `setAuthenticationScheme()` is to locate the `Bearer` token in the resource call

Answer (score 1):

Below class gives the clear idea what authenticaiton scheme means

```
public enum AuthenticationScheme {

    /**
     * Send an Authorization header.
     */
    header,

    /**
     * Send a query parameter in the URI.
     */
    query,

    /**
     * Send in the form body.
     */
    form,

    /**
     * Do not send at all.
     */
    none
}
```

Enumeration of possible methods for transmitting authentication credentials.